# Limit the Number of columns displayed in a Table from foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css, forms, html-table

I have a Loop which is outputting data into a html form and table. How can I limit the number of columns it displays, the reason i wanna do this is because i have limited space and the loop might run for 1000 times or even more depending on the user.

I want to Limit the Columns to say 6, so if the loop runs 6 times I want it to create a new row for another 6 columns and repeat again.

```
<form method="POST" action="script.php">
<table><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="itemSelect[]" class="itemSelect" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></td>
<td>
<div class="item-box" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $value['image_inventory']; ?>.png">
    <div id="rarity">
       <p> <?php
                if (!isset($value['item_rarity'])) {
                    $rarity = "common";
                     echo $rarity;
                } else {
                    $rarity = $value['item_rarity'];
                     echo $rarity;
                }
            ?> </p>
    </div>

</div></td>
 </tr> </table>
 <?php
}

 }
?> 
 </table>
<button type="Submit">
    Send Trade Offer
</button>
```

Comment: you did not provide the important part of the code (the loop), also I can't fully understand what you want to do. it seems to me you'll need javascript, or to hide > 6

Comment: Use modulo. You want to end the row after 6 columns and add a new one? Something like `if($iRowCount % 6 == 0) echo "</tr><tr>";` inside your loop (with a row counter).

Answer (score 0):

this should help, adjust the columns as needed:

```
<?php
$data = array_fill(0,100,"text");
$i = 0;
$columns = 8;
$rest = $columns-(count($data)%$columns);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($data as $cell): ?>
            <?php if(!($i%$columns)) echo '</tr><tr>'?>
            <td><?= $cell ?></td>
            <?php $i++;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <!-- fill rest cells-->
        <?php if($rest<$columns):for($r=0;$r<$rest;$r++): ?>
            <td>fill</td>
        <?php endfor;endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

P.S- could be a better Idea to not use a table at all and just float each "cell" left (use a div element for example) that way the layout would be responsive